# How to export an Eclipse Database (JDBC) project and make it executable on user's pc?

Tags: database, eclipse, oracle, jdbc, executable

I have created Dental Registry application on eclipse which is connected to Oracle 11 g Database using JDBC. Everything is complete.

Now I want to export the project and make it runnable on someone else' computer.

I am planning to distribute to as many people as possible. My users don't have access to internet if anything involves it. I have no idea how to make it keep running without user not needing to install Oracle on their computer. It is just like installing a program on someone's computer (like creating .exe file).

Please give me any suggestion. This is the first time for me doing this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to install Oracle client if JDBC thin driver is used. If your eclipse project is eclipse RCP application, there is Export menu. If it is 'ordinal' Java Swing application - pack your code in jar + add file containing something like java -cp jar1;jar2 MainClass. To automate it, look at ant or maven.
 If you need user friendly installation, find some product that does that...